# PHP Redirect with header then execute code on new page from redirected page

Tags: php, html, header

Is it possible to use header to redirect a user to a page but execute the PHP code from the redirected page to the new page?

```
//This is my form handling page

if (empty($first_name)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo 'Please fill in username';
}
```

Comment: Sure: `header('Location: index.php?errors[]=username_required&errors[]=password_required;etc...');` And then use the `$_GET` superglobal to detect and show the error texts.

Comment: That worked like a charm. So easy to.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use something like :

```
if(empty($first_name)){
   include 'index.php';
   echo 'Please fill in username';
   exit();
}
```

Comment: That's not going to help. No one is ever going to see the `echo`, the `exit` doesn't matter.

Comment: That'll just execute on the form handling page and not on index.php. I won't even see it.